# Problems with beamer's overlayarea

Tags: beamer, luatex

The [beamer manual](https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) states in section 9.5:

> The trouble with this approach is that it may lead to slight, but
> annoying differences in the heights of the lines, which may cause the
> whole frame to “wobble” from slide to slide. This problem becomes much
> more severe if the replacement text is several lines long.
>
> To solve this problem, you can use two environments: `overlayarea` and
> `overprint`. The first is more flexible, but less user-friendly.

So I attempted to make use of this `overlayarea` environment in order to show the progress of how a certain type of parser works.

An MWE created from it looks like this (LuaLaTeX only!):

```
\ifdefined\directlua\else
    \errmessage{LuaTeX is required to typeset this document}
    \csname @@end\expandafter\endcsname
\fi
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\begin{frame}{Something's odd}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
        \ttfamily
        \begin{onlyenv}<1>
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Some text
                \item Some more text
            \end{itemize}
        \end{onlyenv}

        \begin{onlyenv}<2>
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Some text
                \item Some more text ... really, possibly much more ...
            \end{itemize}
        \end{onlyenv}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The mentioned wobble effect also occurs without enabling `lua-visual-debug`, but *with* it one can see the difference better.

Please note that subsequent slides behave just like slide two, which is why I didn't include any further slides. That is: the wobble happens in the transition from slide one to slide two, but not after that point.

You can see the problem quite nicely in this GIF I created:

[image: The wobble effect when transitioning between slides one and two]

The vertical glue before the first item appears only on the second slide (and subsequent ones), but not on the first one.

**Question:** how can I get rid of this wobble effect, even for the transition between slide one and two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a `beamer` overlay or a color change or any other "invisible" thing affects spacing it's (very nearly almost) always due to whatsit nodes appearing in vertical mode.

So the trick is to start horizontal mode first.

```
\ifdefined\directlua\else
    \errmessage{LuaTeX is required to typeset this document}
    \csname @@end\expandafter\endcsname
\fi
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\begin{frame}{Something's odd}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
        \ttfamily
        \mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip]\begin{onlyenv}<1>
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Some text
                \item Some more text
            \end{itemize}
        \end{onlyenv}

        \begin{onlyenv}<2>
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Some text
                \item Some more text ... really, possibly much more ...
            \end{itemize}
        \end{onlyenv}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I realise that avoiding vertical mode is unnatural for giraffes, but sometimes it has to be done.

Comment: +1 : What part of the code starts the horizontal mode?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `\mbox{}` or more exactly the `\leavevmode` in the definition of `\mbox`  ( "leave v mode"  clue in the name:-) or more exactly the `\unhbox` in the definition of `\leavevmode`

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up!